# Is there a MySQL seed database dump for Adempiere ERP 380

Tags: mysql, erp, adempiere

I was looking into trying out Adempiere 380 LTS specifically with MySQL. Is there a seed database anywhere that I can use? There used to be one for 360 but I'm not sure if it's still compatible (probably not).

If not any suggestions on a work around. I've started a migration of a seed PostgreSQL to MySQL but the process is slow as it requires quite a bit of manual intervention from the looks of it.

Comment: I don't believe there is a 380 seed for mysql. But I think there is for 370 so perhaps start with it and run the migrations for 380? I've not tried it... it was just a thought.  If it works maybe you could contribute it? ;)

Comment: I could only find one for 360. I'm not sure if I'm going to bother with trying to get it working with MySQL any more but if I do I'll put it somewhere public.

Comment: The MySQL support was contributed by Trifon Trifonov and he has a Adempiere MySQL project on [SourceForge][http://sourceforge.net/projects/adempiere-mysql/] I had thought there was a 370 seed there but I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one at the moment.

The latest MySQL dump, that I can see, is available [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/adempiere-mysql/svn/47/tree/dist/mysql-dist/).

You would need to either successfully migrate latest PosgreSQL database over MySQL (there's something called [pg2mysql](http://www.lightbox.ca/pg2mysql.php), mysql workbench also has a migration tool) or try to adapt 360's MySQL dump to the latest version of Adempiere.

Whatever the option, there's going to be quite a bit of manual work to get it working 100%.